# jaxb list with one element

Tags: json, list, jaxb, singleton

I produce JSON with a List<> member inside. It is marshalled OK.

However, my consuming (third-)party complains about a missing []-pair, when the list has only one element. What I produce is like:

```
"mylist":{"id":104,"name":"Only one found"} // produced
```

while my consumer expects:

```
"mylist":[{"id":104,"name":"Only one found"}] // expected by third party
```

Is my implementation producing incorrect JSON?

Answer (score 3):

**Note:**  I'm the [**EclipseLink JAXB (MOXy)**](http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/moxy.php) lead and a member of the [**JAXB (JSR-222)**](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=222) expert group.

The JAXB (JSR-222) specification does not cover JSON-binding.  The behaviour you are seeing is most likely due to a JAXB implementation being used with a library like Jettison.  Jettison converts StAX events to/from JSON and can only detect a list when an element occurs more than once (see:  http://blog.bdoughan.com/2011/04/jaxb-and-json-via-jettison.html).  EclipseLink JAXB offers native JSON binding and can correctly represent arrays of size 1.

**JAVA MODEL**

**Foo**

```java
import java.util.List;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.*;

@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Foo {

    private List<Bar> mylist;

}
```

**Bar**

```java
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.*;

@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Bar {

    private int id;
    private String name;

}
```

**jaxb.properties**

To specify MOXy as your JAXB provider you need to include a file called `jaxb.properties` in the same package as your domain model with the following entry (see: http://blog.bdoughan.com/2011/05/specifying-eclipselink-moxy-as-your.html):

```
javax.xml.bind.context.factory=org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBContextFactory
```

**DEMO CODE**

**Demo**

```
import java.util.*;
import javax.xml.bind.*;
import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamSource;
import org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBContextProperties;

public class Demo {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Map<String, Object> properties = new HashMap<String, Object>(2);
        properties.put(JAXBContextProperties.MEDIA_TYPE, "application/json");
        properties.put(JAXBContextProperties.JSON_INCLUDE_ROOT, false);
        JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(new Class[] {Foo.class}, properties);

        Unmarshaller unmarshaller = jc.createUnmarshaller();
        StreamSource json = new StreamSource("src/forum15404528/input.json");
        Foo foo = unmarshaller.unmarshal(json, Foo.class).getValue();

        Marshaller marshaller = jc.createMarshaller();
        marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
        marshaller.marshal(foo, System.out);
    }

}
```

**input.json/Output**

We see that the `mylist` is correctly represented as a JSON array.

```
{
   "mylist" : [ {
      "id" : 104,
      "name" : "Only one found"
   } ]
}
```

**ADDITIONAL INFORMATION**

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2011/08/json-binding-with-eclipselink-moxy.html
- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2012/05/moxy-as-your-jax-rs-json-provider.html

Comment: Since Blaise hinted at a specific implementation, I asked in the TomEE forum. Seems there was an issue prior to the TomEE+ 1.5.1 I am using now: http://openejb.979440.n4.nabble.com/json-list-returning-one-element-lacks-square-bracket-pair-tc4661524.html. My problem is not solved (yet), but now I have clue how to solve it.